# Convert a multiband raster to a polygon in qgis

Tags: qgis, multi-band

My version of QGIS is 2.8.

I want to convert a RGB raster into a polygon. I just need the boundary of it (not the rectangle extent but the boundary of the real feature). I have tried raster calculator but it says SAGA does not support multiband raster.

I also have tried the Vectorize raster layer tool but it takes a very long time because the resolution is very high. It gives me around 3000000 polygon for an image like below and I have a few hundreds this size of images.

Is there any other way to do it?
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add screenshot of raster ?

Comment: yes, I just did it.

Comment: Have you looked at the Image Boundary plugin in QGIS?

Comment: I did but for some reasons it gives me a rectangular extent

Comment: Try using the "valid pixels" option.

Comment: @Aaron I did that, but still

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured it out... Use Raster Calculator:

band@1 * 0 + band@2 * 0 + band@3 * 0

Then will get a raster of two values, then vectorizing this raster will only take a second.

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps, it might not be the best but it serves the purpose. It is based also on vectorization of Raster but with additional step:

1) **Resample** the Raster image to a lowest resolution.
follow below link for example http://dominoc925.blogspot.sg/2015/04/resampling-single-geotiff-image-in-qgis.html
2) Use **Raster to vector** feature in QGIS.
https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/raster_to_vector.html
3) Use the **Dissolve** feature to merge all polygons and form one final polygon.

You mentioned you have hundreds of files, why not using the **Model builder** to automate the process:
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/processing_graphical_modeler.html

Comment: But if I do that I will lose details on the edge? btw thanks for mentioning the Model Builder but I am planning to do it in the python console

Comment: I have been thinking to convert the image into a single band image, then use raster calculator to calculate all the pixel with value to 1, then turn that into 1 polygon. However, I can't find any way to convert the image in QGIS

Comment: It is not converting, it is extracting a band from multiband raster. Check this link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62133/how-to-export-only-one-band-from-an-image-using-gdal