# Algorithm split image doesn't show up anymore in QGIS 2.18.14

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, otb-applications

I developed a plugin for qgis in python language with a code line to execute split image algorithm from orfeo toolbox. When I update from QGIS 2.18.9 to 2.18.14 the split image algorithm doesn't show up in the processing toolbox and when I run the plugin I created, QGIS crashes because it can not find the algorithm.

I reinstalled QGIS and also reinstalled windows but I cannot find that algorithm in processing toolbox.

Is there an alternative to separate multispectral image in bands?

Comment: If all you need to do is extract each band as its own file or layer, gdal_translate is an effective tool:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62133/how-to-export-only-one-band-from-an-image-using-gdal

Answer (score 1):

If you rely on Orfeo toolbox, I advice you to use QGIS 2.14.20 LTR (Long Term Release) the split tool is still there. I am not sure why the Split Image tool is removed from QGIS 2.18.14 but I can confirm that QGIS 2.14.20 still has the Split image tool:

QGIS 2.14.20 (Split image tool exists):

[image]

QGIS 2.18.14 (Split image tool does not exist):

[image]

Comment: Yes, i tried QGIS 2.14.20 LTR but it doesn't have another algorithm thai i've implemented on plugin: i.segment from GRASS GIS 7.

Comment: Now this is another question. You said you didn't find `Slit Image` tool from Orfeo toolbox. You did mention anything about `i.segement` tool from GRASS 7. Please clarify your question and give more details.

Comment: I tried to say that QGIS 2.18.14 doesn't have now the algorithm split image from otb  but has i.segment from GRASS GIS 7. 
QGIS 2.14.20 LTR has split image from otb but doesn't have i.segment from GRASS GIS 7.

Comment: I am not if this can help you or not, but try to install Orfeo toolbox directly from https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/. It may contain `Split Image` tool and use it in your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall QGIS 2.18. You can run the split image from bin folder.
Find in your computer  otbgui_SplitImage.bat (this bat is within the bin folder of your OTB version).
Run as administrator. Probably, windows will block the execution, click in more details and click run anyway.
In my computer, I am doing this until I figure out other(best) solution.

Regards