# How to export selected bands from an image using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, image

I have a multi-band GeoTIFF (with 8 bands), and I want to extract first 3 band and 7th band from that image and export them as TIFF image using GDAL.

Bands details given by dataset is shown in following image
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export only one band from an image using GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62133/how-to-export-only-one-band-from-an-image-using-gdal)

Comment: That answer is for extracting one band. I want to extract 4 different bands(RED, GREEN, BLUE and Near-IR). and combine them in final output

Comment: Do it four times, merge the output

Comment: Is there any sequence of bands in general?
Because in above photo bands i required are (2,3,5,7). 
that's why i am confused , if i do it four times which bands will be picked?

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -b 7 input.tif output.tif
```